# How to adjust for Query Planner's inaccurate row estimates

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 9.5.4.

I have a query that, after running analyze goes from taking a few seconds to taking 30+ minutes. I've read about the different cost parameters and played with them, I've increased default_statics_target to 10000 (and analyzed again), I've vacuumed, I've re-indexed, etc.
Having looked at the EXPLAIN output for the query, I identified the problem - the query planner estimates only 1 row for an operation when in fact there are 5000+ (as seen by EXPLAIN ANALYZE). As a result, the query is choosing to perform nested loops (instead of hash joins); and given that it believes there is only one row I don't think tweaks to the cost parameter will fix anything (if it believes the cost is near 0 then changing what we multiply it by won't change its choice)

In my case, I found that dropping a relevant index is forcing Postgresql to use a hash join which fixed the performance, but this 'solution' is very specific to this query and table (and one I don't understand).

So my question is this: In *general*, when the query planner drastically underestimates the number of rows for an operation (or overestimates), how can I correct it so that it can find better plans?

On top of that, if your queries are often suffering from the planner underestimating the rows for them, are there tips for writing them differently to avoid this?

(One reference for others on why the planner can estimate the rows so badly is [here](https://blog.pgaddict.com/posts/common-issues-with-planner-statistics) under 'Dependent columns')

Comment: I think that question is too general for a good answer.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not expecting much more than a 'best practices' type of answer.

Comment: `it believes there is only one row` text / varchar columns ?

Comment: 1) How many range table entries? 2) data model up to BCNF? 3) Tables with  two or more Candidate Keys ? 4) Searching/joining on non-key attributes?

Comment: @wildplasser There are some text columns that contain only a handful of possible values
1.) 6
2.) I'm not sure; the data structure is fairly normal but I don't know/understand the exact definitions for normality.
3.) I'm not familiar with that terminology; the only unique keys are the primary keys
4.) Yes; some of the text columns are used in simple equality statements.

Remember that I'm not trying to debug my existing query; it works well under the right execution strategy and I can get it to run under that one. I'm just interested in best practices for future queries.

Comment: 0) if you *know* that a subquery on a subset of the needed tables yields only a couple of result tuples, you could squeeze these into a CTE, in most cases forcing a (maybe two ...) hash joins. 1) Ok; (0) could help here, too 2) so there still could be transitive dependencies .. 3) cardinality of the FKs ? 4) suspect. Are these the sparse-statistics ones? (also: encoding?) BTW: there is a known issue with the Most Common Values in the statistics (could be fixed in Pg9.6) , Your problem *could* be a manifestation of this.

Comment: 3.) It's usually one to many. Do you have a reference to the issue with Most Common Values I can read to see if it might be related? 

One of my coworkers has been having a problem with an unrelated query, and, suspecting it was a similar problem, I tested it with the debug setting of enable_nestlopp = off and it ran in 2 minutes (from taking over 60+ minutes. I can't share the queries or the tables (proprietary), but I think I can create a general example. Would that be useful?

Comment: Yes, that would be useful ... FYI: just the plain developers mailing list: (about 3 month ago, IIRC) Basically this thread, I think: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACACo5RFCsMDZrsxwzZ0HsCBY51EttXB%3DHwZhfp%2BX7EGRgeSSQ%40mail.gmail.com [but I still think your problem is a database modelling  issue ... ]